# Constraints layout to UITextFields in a cell

Tags: storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

Trying to find options to add constraints to a `UITextField` that are in a table cell row. I'm trying to keep both of them 50% of the width and/either (pinned to the left right edges).

Not sure what constraints to add to achieve it in the Interface builder. Please advise.

[image: storyboard screenshot]

**Edit.**

After following steps, few more things to go. **Widths of the textfields are not** 50% of the available space in the cell, how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what the `multiplier` does?

Comment: no idea about multiplier

Comment: Well, the `multiplier` is how you say "50% of the width".

Comment: Describe what constraints you already have, please.

Comment: @matt no constraints, I'm starting from scratch, new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make equal widths and horizontal spacing for textfields. Also pin left to left, right to right and center vertically for both.

UPDATED:

**Select two textfields and do:**

1. Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Clear Constraints
2. Editor -> Pin -> Horizontal Spacing and
3. Editor -> Pin -> Widths Equally
4. Editor -> Align -> Vertical Centers

**Select left textfield and do:**

1. Editor -> Pin -> Leading Space to Superview

**Select right textfield and do:**

1. Editor -> Pin -> Trailing Space to Superview.

Comment: If he does that, he'll have unsatisfiable constraints.

Comment: first of all If I click textField then -> Pin -> Equal widths is disabled

Comment: select two textFields and Equal widths will be available, or ctrl drag from one textfield to another

Comment: @ChikabuZ found, set the equal widths, not sure about the horizontal spacing, which option is this? Also when you say pin left to left meaning drag and drop the textField to the left or the right when it snaps to the margin of the parent view?

Comment: Select left textfields and press Editor -> Pin -> Leading Space to Superview, for right - Trailing Space to Superview.
Select two textfields and press Editor -> Pin -> Horizontal Spacing and Widths Equally; Editor -> Align -> Vertical Centers

Comment: @ChikabuZ perfect, thanks for the mini tutorial, few more things to go, I'm posting an edit with a screenshot.

Comment: Also under the FirstName constraints it says -> Width - (195), I guess it's 195 px, however, I want the width to be stretchable, 50% of iPad or iPhone that's what we do in html/css, how do we do that with constraints?